# Ubicar una etiqueta creada en una determinada posición

Tags: javascript

He creado una etiqueta *h1* y la he insertado al div, pero esta se ubica en la última posición y no en la primera ¿cómo hago para que se ubique en la primera posición?

```js
var agregar = document.querySelector(".list");

function insertar() {
var crear = document.createElement("h1");
crear.innerText = "Información del producto";
agregar.appendChild(crear);
}
insertar();
```

```html
<div class="list">
<p>Cantidad del producto</p>
<span>200L</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Procede de esta forma:

- Quita el uso del método `appenChild`
- Obtén y asigna a una variable el elemento `p` que ya existe
- Usa el método `insertBefore`

El método `insertBefore` te va a solicitar:

- Elemento a ingresar (es decir la etiqueta), que en este caso sería la etiqueta del `h1`que se llama crear
- Elemento que estará después del que planeas registrar que en este caso es `parrafo`

Código:

```html
    <div class="list">
    <p>Cantidad del producto</p>
    <span>200L</span>
    </div>
    
    <script>
    var agregar = document.querySelector(".list");
    
    function insertar() {
    var crear = document.createElement("h1");
    let parrafo = document.querySelector("p")
    crear.innerText = "Información del producto";
    agregar.insertBefore(crear, parrafo);
    }
    insertar();
    </script>
```

**Referencia**

- [método insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/insertarAntes)

Answer (score 0):

Un método alternativo sería utilizar el método `prepend` que hace exactamente esto: *inserta el nodo creado en la primera posición.*

```js
    var agregar = document.querySelector(".list");
    
    function insertar() {
    var crear = document.createElement("h1");
    crear.innerText = "Información del producto";
    agregar.prepend(crear);
    }
    insertar();
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <p>Cantidad del producto</p>
    <span>200L</span>
</div>
```