# Cómo añadir un addEventListener a un div

Tags: javascript, html

Me interesa agregar un addEventListener a un div pero no me funciona como lo tengo, cómo hago para que cargue la funciones una vez cargue el div?

```js
var agregar = document.querySelector(".archive");

agregar.addEventListener("load", function(){});
```

```html
<div class="archive">
</div>
```

Comment: Esto [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/335828/ubicar-una-etiqueta-creada-en-una-determinada-posici%c3%b3n) no responde tu duda?, me parece muy similar la necesidad expuesta

Comment: @Aprendiz ya edité la publicación, tenía la plantilla pre-creada de la antigua pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que como lo planteas no es correcto debido a que:

- `load` es un evento que verifica cuando la página completa ha sido cargada, lo cual se sale de la intención cuando tu lo que deseas es verificar solo que un `div` se encuentre creado en el *DOM*
- Dado lo anterior me parece mas adecuado que si deseas verificar que ese `div` ya *exista* entonces deberías apoyarte del objeto de mas alto nivel que es `window`
- Ahora aunque en la intención de uso no esta mas explicado, me parece que lo mas adecuado sería que uses el evento `DOMContentLoaded`

Tu código debería verse así:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
    </head>
      <div class="archive"></div>
    <body>
    <script>
      let archivo = document.querySelector(".archive")
      
      window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        console.log(`El div con class: ${archivo.className} si existe`)
      })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Enlace de interés**

- [load y DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)